# Customize HTML output of ASP checkboxlist in Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, checkboxlist

I'm currently using the checkboxlist element and binding data server side, but it displays an HTML table and checkbox items inside, so it breaks my layout. Is there a way of customizing its outputs, so far I have only found how to add CSS classes and that's not what I'm aiming at.

Also is there any other way to create dynamic lists of components on ASP.NET that allow me to get the value of all of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following properties allow to customize the CheckBoxList layout:

[RepeatLayout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.repeatlayout(v=vs.110).aspx): select the type of container (table, span, ordered list, unordered list)
[RepeatColumns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.repeatcolumns(v=vs.110).aspx): set the number of columns (for table layout)
[RepeatDirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.repeatdirection(v=vs.110).aspx): choose between horizontal and vertical display

If you want more control and more freedom on the type of HTML element used to display your data, you can use use a Repeater or a ListView.

Comment: Worth noting that the `ul` and `li` options for repeat layout are new to Asp 4 for people still stuck on 3.5